# Join to subquery not working?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I should be able to reference tables in the join clauses from a subquery, shouldn't I?

But the following query is giving me errors saying they can't be bound:

```
select *
from call c
JOIN call_task ct ON c.call_no=ct.call_no AND ct.calltask_no = (select min(ict.calltask_no) FROM call_task ict WHERE ict.call_no=c.call_no)
JOIN business b ON c.service_business_id=b.business_id
JOIN item i ON ct.item_id=i.item_id
JOIN    (   select top 1 * 
            FROM contract_line icl
            WHERE   icl.item_id = i.item_id 
                AND icl.location_no = c.service_location_no 
                AND icl.business_id = b.business_id
            ORDER BY icl.cancel_date asc
        ) cl ON i.item_id=cl.item_id 
             AND cl.location_no=c.service_location_no 
             AND cl.business_id=b.business_id
JOIN [contract] co ON cl.cont_no=co.cont_no
JOIN business_location bl ON bl.business_id=c.service_business_id AND bl.location_no=c.service_location_no
WHERE b.bus_code='INGRAM04'
AND ct.cont_no is null
AND call_sts NOT IN ('BB', 'BI', 'CA', 'CL', 'IP')
--AND cl.end_date > c.entry_date
ORDER BY c.create_time
```

The errors are:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "i.item_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "c.service_location_no" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.business_id" could not be bound.

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors, and can't think of any way around it.  The item_no on a contract_line can appear more than once on a contract, if it was canceled and a new line created for instance.  In those cases I need to ignore the cancelled line and pull the current one.  Doing the subquery and ordering by cancel_date pulls the nulls first so it accomplishes what I want... but this weird binding error is screwing me up.  I know I've used this technique before so now I'm confused...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use dependent sub-queries in JOIN. Use APPLY instead. Using KM's example:

```
declare @table table (t int);
select     t1.t     
from @table t1    
cross apply (select t2.t from @table t2 where t1.t=t2.t) as dt
```

Comment: Took me a while to understand CROSS APPLY... but that did the trick.  (I still swear I've done the subquery thing before though...)

Comment: There are some semantic differences between JOIN and APPLY so you have to exercise caution, but in general whenever one wants to join with a right side set that is dependent on the current row of the left side set, APPLY is the way to go. Given that you have TOP and ORDER that have to apply *after* the WHERE that is dependent on c and b aliases, I think APPLY is appropiate.

Answer (score 1):

The error I believe is coming from the select you are aliasing with cl then trying to join on

```
WHERE   icl.item_id = i.item_id 
AND icl.location_no = c.service_location_no 
AND icl.business_id = b.business_id
```

you can't reference "i" and "c" and "b" there.

Answer (score 0):

that is not a sub query, but a derived table (or some call it an inline view).  here is a simple query to show the same problem:

```
declare @table table (t int)
select 
    t1.t 
    from @table t1
    inner join (select t2.t from @table t2 where t1.t=t2.t) dt on 1=1

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "t1.t" could not be bound.
```

everything between the `( )` is isolated from the outer query.

this is a subquery that works:

```
select 
    t1.t 
    from @table t1
    WHERE exists (select * from @Table t2 where t1.t=t2.t)
```

OUTPUT:

```
t
-----------

(0 row(s) affected)
```